# generating random numbers on a kivy label

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, kivy

I want to show randomly generated numbers on a kivy label which is similar to a countdown animation.

**prototype.py (python file):**

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    import random
    import time


    class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
        def do(self):
            a = 0
            total = 5
            user = self.ids.name
            while a <= 10:
                randnum = random.randrange(total)
                user.text = str(randnum)

                a+=1


    class prototypeApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return RootWidget()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        no=prototypeApp()
        no.run()
```

**prototype.kv (kv file):**

```
    <RootWidget>:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            id: name
            text:''
            font_size:70
            height:70
        Button:
            text:'click me'
            on_release:app.root.do()
            size_hint_y:.1
```

There was no error but on the label, it displays only the last number
of the randomly generated numbers.
But I expected the numbers in the loop to flow smoothly on the  label not show me only the last number in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop in the `do()` method is run on the main thread, which is the same thread that updates the GUI. Since it is a single thread, the GUI cannot be updated until your `do()` method completes, which means that only the last random number gets displayed in the GUI.

To fix that, run that loop in a separate thread (see [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html)). And you will need to execute the `self.ids.name.text = str(randnum)` back on the main thread (consider using [Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) to accomplish that).

You will probably want to add a [sleep](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html?highlight=sleep#time.sleep) in the loop, otherwise it will probably happen too fast to see the intermediate numbers.